# Why is WSL taking up more disk space than it says it is?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My disk filled up so I checked what was taking up all the space and Settings said that my Ubuntu distro for WSL was taking up 120GB as shown here:

[image]

Then I ran `sudo ncdu / --exclude /mnt` in WSL and it said it was only taking up 53.8GiB (57.8GB) of disk space.

Does anyone know what is causing this discrepancy in disk usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSL2 works like a virtual machine; the guest OS doesn't directly store individual files in your host filesystem – it has a dedicated virtual "disk" that is stored in a single large `.vhdx` file as seen by Windows.

This file grows dynamically as the guest OS writes data to new "disk" areas, but **does not shrink** when those areas are no longer used. For example, if the virtual disk had sectors 10000-20000 in use by a large file and you removed it, the space for those sectors (and their data, too) is still consumed by the VHDX file.

So over time, as Ubuntu places new files all over the disk area, the VHDX will continue growing until it eventually reaches the complete "disk size" that was given to the VM.

Automatic compaction of the VHD used by WSL2 was actually added [earlier this week](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-subsystem-for-linux-september-2023-update/#automatic-disk-space-clean-up-set-sparse-vhd).

If this were a dedicated Hyper-V VM, it would need to run periodic `fstrim` to inform the host OS of which VHD areas may be considered "free" (the same as what you'd use with SSDs); I suspect the new WSL2 feature works the same way, only performing the trim from its "system distro".

Comment: I spotted that, but when I run `wsl --manage Ubuntu-22.04 --set-sparse true`  it returns `Invalid command line argument: --manage`

Comment: Have you actually upgraded to the latest WSL2 release? (And, well, I was assuming you're using WSL2 and not WSL1 because that's generally the default.)

Comment: Yes I am on WSL2. I also checked windows updates and ran `wsl --update` to install any updates that maybe had not installed. Apparently everything is up to date, but the above command gives the same output.

Comment: WSL was installed from Windows Store or optional Windows Feature? Only the copy from Windows Store is updated

Comment: It turns out that the version of the WSL2 kernel that allows the above command is a pre-release. Hence, the it is only possible to update to that version using `wsl --update --pre-release`. After doing that I was able to run the above command successfully.

Comment: I am just not sure how long it takes to kick in...

Comment: Try manually running `fstrim -av` on your WSL2 (after fully restarting it). From the terminology ("sparse" VHDX as opposed to compaction), it sounds like the VHDX file will only reduce its physical size ("Size on Disk" in the Properties dialog) but will still show the same logical size, so while it will indeed free up space, I'm not entirely sure whether the Settings app will correctly report that.

Comment: That doesn't give any lines of output - I don't think it did anything

Comment: I suspect that the feature which frees the disk space can only free memory when the files are deleted after the feature has been enabled. It probably isn't smart enough to compact the virtual hard drive by itself. I ended up compacting the virtual hard drive file with diskpart (which freed up 32GB) and then setting it to sparse. Hopefully this works moving forward.